# Azure DevOps Rest API - Unable To Create New Iteration

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to use REST API to create iterations for a project using POST as per this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/post%20team%20iteration?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

However I keep getting a 400 response.

Curiously I added one in the UI (Iteration 3) - and when I request the results it does not include the new one.

Is there an issue with this not really working properly or am I doing something wrong?

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectId}/{teamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

```
{
count: 3,
value: [
{
id: "f95df712-1f2d-4685-86ea-b2e7dbad8353",
name: "Iteration 0",
path: "CMMI2\Iteration 0",
attributes: {
startDate: null,
finishDate: null,
timeFrame: "current"
},
url: "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectId}/{teamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/f95df712-1f2d-4685-86ea-b2e7dbad8353"
},
{
id: "ec4f29f0-0b48-4a52-9b71-45e396654330",
name: "Iteration 1",
path: "CMMI2\Iteration 1",
attributes: {
startDate: null,
finishDate: null,
timeFrame: "future"
},
url: "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectId}/{teamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/ec4f29f0-0b48-4a52-9b71-45e396654330"
},
{
id: "ab3d8626-c613-48ff-9378-f3b7ed109d77",
name: "Iteration 2",
path: "CMMI2\Iteration 2",
attributes: {
startDate: null,
finishDate: null,
timeFrame: "future"
},
url: "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectId}/{teamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/ab3d8626-c613-48ff-9378-f3b7ed109d77"
}
]
}
```

Comment: you'll have to do 2 requests. first create the classificationnode and then assign that classificationnode using the iterations-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new iteration, you have to use another urls. You can find them here: [Classification Nodes - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/create%20or%20update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). Sample of Create iteration:

> POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?api-version=5.0
>
> Request Body
>
> JSON
>
> {
>    "name": "Final Iteration",
>    "attributes": {
>
> "startDate": "2014-10-27T00:00:00Z",
>
> "finishDate": "2014-10-31T00:00:00Z"
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: Is there a way to use this across multiple projects within the organisation? I've just tested this and it fails because the Iteration Name is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the new iteration because you added the iteration in `Project configuration` only, the Rest API is related to "team settings".

You need also to add the iteration in `Team configuration` (when you click on it you have tab "iterations", then click "Select iteration(s)" and select the new one).

If you want help about the creating iteration you must share here all the code you tried.